# How many "or" should be written in case of three or more choices?

Tags: conjunctions, lists

How many "**or**" should be written in case of three or more choices?

For example: 
when having three choices, I can write two times "**or**", or just one time as follow:

> black **or** white **or** red.

or

> black, white **or** red

Answer (score 4):

You can drop the first repeated "or", unless you wish to keep the repetition for emphasis.

So while your second example is preferred, the first is also allowed.